# when i first install app ,the preview window is not show video. i have to exit my app and enter again ,make video call is normal

Tags: android, video

> pjsua_vid_dev_set_setting(dev_id, PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_CAP_ORIENTATION,
>   &orient, keep) 07-27 11:59:39.958 16897-16897/ I/System.out: Code:
>   520008 07-27 11:59:39.958 16897-16897/ I/System.out: Description:
>   Invalid or unsupported video capability (PJMEDIA_EVID_INVCAP) 07-27
>   11:59:39.958 16897-16897/ I/System.out: Location:
>   ../src/pjsua2/media.cpp:1510

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: please elaborate your problem